# matplotlibでy軸の特定の目盛の色を変える

Tags: python, matplotlib

matplotlibでy軸の特定の目盛の色を変えたいと考えています．
ｙ軸の2,3,8の値の色を青に変えたいです．

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tick

plt.yticks([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
           ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"])

plt.show()
```

解決方法がわかりません．よろしくお願いします．

Answer (score 4):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tick

_, labels = plt.yticks(
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"])
labels[2].set_color("green")
labels[3].set_color("yellow")
labels[8].set_color("red")
plt.show()
```

`yticks()` ([matplotlib.pyplot.yticks](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=yticks#matplotlib.pyplot.yticks)) は`YTick`の配列(ここでは要らないので`_`に代入) と`Text`の配列を返すので、色を変えたい`Text`に対して`set_color()`([matplotlib.text.Text.set_color](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=yticks#matplotlib.pyplot.yticks)) を呼びだせば変えられます。

提示された例では 0, 1, 2, ... と ticks が単純でしたが、そうでない場合は `Text` の `get_text()` ([matplotlib.text.Text.get_text](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html?highlight=get_text#matplotlib.text.Text.get_text)) を呼び出し、tick の文字列を確認した上で色を変えたほうがいいかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました．